# Hide a list with jquery

Tags: jquery, list

I have a nested list as a navigation tool for a mobile website. The a.close-link in last li should close/hide the list #menu with jquery:

```
<ul id="navi">

<li><a href="#">Mobile Navigation</a>  

<ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="close">Close parent list</a></li>

</ul>                       
</li>                               
</ul>
```

My working jquery solution so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a.close").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Problem: The list stays on the status "hide" - that means the nested navigation list #menu cannot be openend again. How can I add a line of jquery to get back to the default status?

Thank you for helping!

---

Thank you for your help! You inspired the right solution:

```
<ul id="navi">
<li><a class="openul" href="#">Mobile Navigation</a>  
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="close">Close parent list</a></li>
</ul>                       
</li>                               
</ul>
```

And the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a.close").click(function() {
        $("#menu").children().hide();
        return false;
    });
    $(".openul").mouseover(function() {
        $("#menu").children().show();
    });
});
```

It is very useful for mobile browsers because navigation lists stay open on mouseover.

Comment: why you not put hide link outside menu container

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ul id="navi">

<li><a href="#">Mobile Navigation</a>  

<a class="openul" href="#" style="display:none">Open parent list</a>

<ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="close">Close parent list</a></li>

</ul>                       
</li>                               
</ul>
```

Create a `<a>` and hide it, then when you click to close your parent list, display that `<a>`. That `<a>` onclick will re open your `#menu` and hide itself

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {            
        $("li a.close").click(function() {
            $("#menu").hide();
            $(".openul").show();
            return false;
        });   
    $(".openul").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $("#menu").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update after edited it :D, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yJ63j/1/) working now :D

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a.close").click(function() {
        $("#menu").children().hide();
        return false;
    });
    $(".openul").mouseover(function() {
        $("#menu").children().show();
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Hide the Close li on page load
$("li a.open").parent().hide();

// On click of close, hide the close li and open the show li
$("li a.close").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
    return false;
});

// On click of open, hide the show li and open the close li
$("li a.open").click(function () {
   $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().prev().show();
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RNnmp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. You inspired the right solution:

```
<ul id="navi">
<li><a class="openul" href="#">Mobile Navigation</a>  
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="close">Close parent list</a></li>
</ul>                       
</li>                               
</ul>
```

And the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a.close").click(function() {
        $("#menu").children().hide();
        return false;
    });
    $(".openul").mouseover(function() {
        $("#menu").children().show();
    });
});
```